# Center gravity property for text doesn't work in android button

Tags: android, android-layout, button, layout-gravity

I have two `button` in my layout inside my `TableLayout`, but the text is not in center, I try to use `android:gravity="center"` and android `android:layout_gravity="center"`, but seems it doesn't work.

How can i fix this? thanks in advance

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/bawah"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        >
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="10">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Approve"
                    android:textColor="@color/putih"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="4.9"
                    android:id="@+id/approve"
                    android:background="@drawable/backhijau"

                    />
                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4.9"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="Tolak"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/putih"
            android:id="@+id/tolak"
            android:background="@drawable/backmerah"
            />


            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work means? Please make it more clear.

Comment: I think you define weightsum that's why it doesn't work

Comment: Hai @jackjay, edited my question

Comment: Hai @ArpitPatel i want to make buttons full the screen

Comment: Why are you using table layout??

Comment: i think because i need to implement weightsum so, i can devide my buttons

Comment: @DennyKurniawan check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's seems fine for me copy and past  this code and let me know

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bawah"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/approve"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="4.9"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Approve"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"

                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tolak"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="4.9"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Tolak"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </TableRow>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: Hai @ArpitPatel this work for me thank you very much, but why no need to include TableLayout?

Comment: because its use less whather you include or not its doesn't effect our layout

Comment: If you want multiple tablerow then you can use TableLayout

Comment: Then why should use `TableRow`, instead use `LinearLayout`.

Comment: We can achive one task using bunch of method it's depends on the developer's liking and intrest. Developer wants to use tablelayout so I gave him a  answer regarding tablelayout.

Answer (score 2):

No need of `TableLayout`, just use `RelativeLayout` and `android:layout_below` property and you will get result as you wanted. Also there is no need to implement `weightSum` property.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/bawah"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Approve"
                    android:textColor="@color/putih"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/approve"
                    android:background="@drawable/backhijau"

                    />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="Tolak"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/approve"
                    android:textColor="@color/putih"
                    android:id="@+id/tolak"
                    android:background="@drawable/backmerah"
                    />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hai, thanks for your help @jackjay, i appreciate it, but i want to make my buttons in one line.

Comment: You said you want them full screen. This is how you can set them as fulllscreen.